# How to search exits value in 2D array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I want to check value in array if exits then show "Exits" otherwise show "Not in Array"..

1).
    I create a array=>

```
    $browse['pro_id'] = $id;
    $browse['pro_name'] = $mobile_details[0]['pro_name'];
    $browse['pro_brand'] = $mobile_details[0]['pro_brand'];
    $browse['pro_price_own'] = $mobile_details[0]['pro_price_own'];
    $mob_arr = $browse;
    print_r($browse);
```

//This print array like this..

```
Array
(
    [pro_id] => mob810013034
    [pro_name] => Galaxy Y S5360
    [pro_brand] => Samsung
    [pro_price_own] => 6291
)
```

2). After this 2 time . i am pusing array in above given array=>

```
array_push($mob_arr,$browse);
print_r($mob_arr);

//This print array like this...


Array
(
    [pro_id] => mob810013034
    [pro_name] => Galaxy Y S5360
    [pro_brand] => Samsung
    [pro_price_own] => 6291 

    [0] => Array
        (
            [pro_id] => mobka10013042
            [pro_name] => A 1
            [pro_brand] => Karbonn
            [pro_price_own] => 6000
        )
)
```

I want to check if [pro_id]=mobka10013042 in whole array then continue; else puch array again in $mob_arr

```
array_push($mob_arr,$browse);
```

I use in_array but its not working for this...

Please Give me suggestion .....

Comment: I think it would be better if you make the structure of your array more consistent. otherwise you have any other reasons to do it like that? :)

Comment: Can u tell me ..how to make better structure array...

Comment: on the second example of your array your having a mix structure putting the other values on a one dimensional associative array structure after the 'pro_price_own' index you made index 0 to have a set of values in an array the same associative array index make it consistent if your using a 2 dimensional array structure it would be better if you could make it that way all the way so in that case you could easily manipulate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to create a structure like this:

```
$myarr = Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [pro_id] => mob810013034
            [pro_name] => Galaxy Y S5360
            [pro_brand] => Samsung
            [pro_price_own] => 6291
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [pro_id] => mobka10013042
            [pro_name] => A 1
            [pro_brand] => Karbonn
            [pro_price_own] => 6000
        )
)
```

Then use pop to retrieve whose values:

```
$mob_arr = array();
while(!empty($myarr))
{
   $temp = array_pop($myarr);
   if($temp['pro_id']!='mobka10013042'){
       array_push($mob_arr,$temp);
   }
}

if(empty($mob_arr)){
 //actions when mob_arr variable is empty
} else {
  //if not
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what the approach is.But this might help to get things started.

```
$mob_arr = array();
$browse['pro_id'] = 'mob810013034';
$browse['pro_name'] = 'Galaxy Y S5360';
$browse['pro_brand'] = 'Samsung';
$browse['pro_price_own'] = '6291';
array_push($mob_arr,$browse);

$browse['pro_id'] = 'mobka10013042';
$browse['pro_name'] = 'A 1';
$browse['pro_brand'] = 'Karbonn';
$browse['pro_price_own'] = '6000';

array_push($mob_arr,$browse);


if(checkId($mob_arr, 'pro_id', 'mobka10013042')) {
  print 'found the value...';
} else {
  print 'no can not find the value...';
}

function checkId($arr, $k, $v) {
  foreach($arr as $browse) {
    if($browse[$k] == $v) {
      return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$i=0;
foreach($mob_arr as $row )
{
   if(is_array($row))
   {
     if(in_array('mobka10013042',$row))
    {
      $i=1;
    }
  }
}

if($i==1)
{
  continue 
}
else
{
  // push another array
}
```